# 'func' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, azure, cmd, visual-studio-code, azure-function-app

Keep getting the error

> 'func' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

[image: Image of error]

when entering `func` into the cmd command line, when following [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-azure-functions#_azure-functions-core-tools) tutorial
I have installed python (3.7.3) and all the correct extensions, so am confused as to why this issues is occuring.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: At a glance, it seems you have skipped this important line: `import azure.functions as func`

Comment: @Błotosmętek I get the same error for import **The term 'import' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.**

Comment: It seems you do not install the extension [Azure Functions Core Tools](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-azure-functions#_azure-functions-core-tools).

Comment: `import` is Python keyword, it should be recognized no matter what. Are you sure you selected Python as your language? See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-azure-functions#_create-the-function step 2, second point.

Comment: Or you could use [npm](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools#windows) to install it. npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools

Comment: the error in question is related to function cli. you can download for windows from the following link 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows%2Ccsharp%2Cbash#v2 

You certainly  need NPM for above func cli.

Comment: Run the following command `npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools` as seen in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/tutorial-vs-code-serverless-python-01#azure-functions-core-tools

Answer (score 25):

I had this issue and the provided answer didn't solve my problem.

**Steps I took to fix (Windows):**

1. Install [Chocolately](https://chocolatey.org/install)
2. Run `choco install azure-functions-core-tools`
3. Finally run `func`:

                 `%%%%%%
                %%%%%%
           @   %%%%%%    @
         @@   %%%%%%      @@
      @@@    %%%%%%%%%%%    @@@
    @@      %%%%%%%%%%        @@
      @@         %%%%       @@
        @@      %%%       @@
          @@    %%      @@
               %%
               %`

**EDIT**

While the above did solve my problem, the underlying issue was that `func` was not on my path, so it was not being recognised as a command.

Comment: Yo da real MVP. Cheers

Comment: If you are using VSCode, don't install the core tools using Choco.   It always installs x86.  VSCode is x64.  Installing core tools using Choco breaks VSCode debugging.

Comment: Do `choco install azure-functions-core-tools-3` to install version 3. Otherwise, it will default to version 2.

Comment: Please note that, as for now, the latest Chocolatey version of the `azure-functions-core-tools` is v3 while v4 is in the town. It can be downloaded from here: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4%2Cwindows%2Ccsharp%2Cportal%2Cbash#install-the-azure-functions-core-tools)

Comment: Didn't see anyone mentioning Winget so just thought I could. I basically used:
- winget install 'Azure Functions Core Tools'
- Restarted my terminal/vscode, and it worked.

Already had NPM installed.

Comment: On a macOS, the solution is long(ish): `/usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet "$HOME/Library/Application Support/VisualStudio/azure-functions-cli/Releases/4.40.0/cli_x64/func.dll"`

Answer (score 15):

As part of prerequisites for Azure Function Core Tools , please make sure npm is installed.

Was able to install on Windows using below links

[Downloading and Installing Node.js and npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm)

[NVM for Windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases)

Once NPM is installed, you can install azure functions using below commands

[image]

Post installation was able to run "func" command successfully.

Additional Documentation Reference

[Azure Functions for Vistal Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-azurefunctions#windows)

Hope the above information helps.

Comment: npm install --global azure-functions-core-tools@4
this works for me...

Comment: Thank you! npm installing this package globally worked https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-functions-core-tools